# Unable to install Jenkins from Helm chart

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes-helm

I'm attempting to install Jenkins from a Helm chart for the first time.

I run

```
helm repo add jenkins https://charts.jenkins.io
helm repo update
helm upgrade --install myjenkins jenkins/jenkins
```

But the service never starts. The pod logs show the following errors:

```
Plugin git:4.10.0 (via credentials:1055.v1346ba467ba1) depends on configuration-as-code:1.55, but there is an older version defined on the top level - configuration-as-code:1.54
        at io.jenkins.tools.pluginmanager.impl.PluginManager.start(PluginManager.java:222)
        at io.jenkins.tools.pluginmanager.impl.PluginManager.start(PluginManager.java:171)
        at io.jenkins.tools.pluginmanager.cli.Main.main(Main.java:70)
        Suppressed: io.jenkins.tools.pluginmanager.impl.PluginDependencyException: Plugin kubernetes:1.30.11 (via credentials:1055.v1346ba467ba1) depends on configuration-as-code:1.55, but there is an older version defined on the top level - configuration-as-code:1.54
                at io.jenkins.tools.pluginmanager.impl.PluginManager.resolveRecursiveDependencies(PluginManager.java:1074)
                at io.jenkins.tools.pluginmanager.impl.PluginManager.findPluginsAndDependencies(PluginManager.java:649)
                at io.jenkins.tools.pluginmanager.impl.PluginManager.start(PluginManager.java:214)
                ... 2 more
        Suppressed: io.jenkins.tools.pluginmanager.impl.PluginDependencyException: Plugin workflow-aggregator:2.6 (via credentials:1055.v1346ba467ba1) depends on configuration-as-code:1.55, but there is an older version defined on the top level - configuration-as-code:1.54
                at io.jenkins.tools.pluginmanager.impl.PluginManager.resolveRecursiveDependencies(PluginManager.java:1074)
                at io.jenkins.tools.pluginmanager.impl.PluginManager.findPluginsAndDependencies(PluginManager.java:649)
                at io.jenkins.tools.pluginmanager.impl.PluginManager.start(PluginManager.java:214)
                ... 2 more
        Suppressed: io.jenkins.tools.pluginmanager.impl.PluginDependencyException: Plugin git:4.10.0 (via credentials:1055.v1346ba467ba1) depends on configuration-as-code:1.55, but there is an older version defined on the top level - configuration-as-code:1.54
                at io.jenkins.tools.pluginmanager.impl.PluginManager.resolveRecursiveDependencies(PluginManager.java:1074)
                at io.jenkins.tools.pluginmanager.impl.PluginManager.findPluginsAndDependencies(PluginManager.java:649)
                at io.jenkins.tools.pluginmanager.impl.PluginManager.start(PluginManager.java:214)
                ... 2 more
Multiple plugin prerequisites not met:
Plugin kubernetes:1.30.11 (via credentials:1055.v1346ba467ba1) depends on configuration-as-code:1.55, but there is an older version defined on the top level - configuration-as-code:1.54,
Plugin workflow-aggregator:2.6 (via credentials:1055.v1346ba467ba1) depends on configuration-as-code:1.55, but there is an older version defined on the top level - configuration-as-code:1.54,
Plugin git:4.10.0 (via credentials:1055.v1346ba467ba1) depends on configuration-as-code:1.55, but there is an older version defined on the top level - configuration-as-code:1.54
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution appears to be to force the Helm chart to install updated plugins. The following values.yaml file allowed me to complete the deployment:

```
controller:
    installPlugins:
    - configuration-as-code:1.55
    - kubernetes:1.31.1 
    - workflow-aggregator:2.6 
    - git:4.10.1
```

Answer (score 2):

There are three options to fix this issue:

1. Remove top level plugins that are dependencies of other plugins you use ("git" and "configuration-as-code" are most likely offenders). However, sometimes plugins could have conflicting dependency versions and then this would not work.
2. Jenkins' `plugins.txt` file supports `:latest` as a version.

So your configuration could look like this:

```
controller:
  installPlugins:
    - configuration-as-code:latest
    - kubernetes:latest
    - workflow-aggregator:latest
    - git:latest
```

3. set `controller.installLatestPlugins` to `false`. This will set to download minimal required version of plugins. So, if you're not using `:latest` specifier yourself then it should work. However, you'll be stuck with the old versions of the plugins.

Answer (score 1):

This `- configuration-as-code:1.55` in values.yml fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can upgrade to the version suggested in the message (after `depends on...`)

```
Plugin kubernetes:1.30.11 (via credentials:1055.v1346ba467ba1) depends on configuration-as-code:1.55, but there is an older version defined on the top level - configuration-as-code:1.54,
Plugin workflow-aggregator:2.6 (via credentials:1055.v1346ba467ba1) depends on configuration-as-code:1.55, but there is an older version defined on the top level - configuration-as-code:1.54,
Plugin git:4.10.0 (via credentials:1055.v1346ba467ba1) depends on configuration-as-code:1.55, but there is an older version defined on the top level - configuration-as-code:1.54
```